# What is the difference between a Rest WS and Servlet

Tags: web-services, rest, web

How do they differ in action? Servlet print html only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Servlet :

--is a web component

--it's a powerful java technology

--managed by a container (namely web server such as tomcat) that generates dynamic content

--platform independent java classes (byte code)

--interacts with web clients as request response paradigm

--Request handling methods

```
  ****doGet,doPost,doDelete,doPut,doOptions,doHead,doTrace****
```

Rest WS (Representational State Transfer Web Service)

--A way to achieving service oriented architecture in web application

--it's an architectural concept

--web service resource is uniquely identifiable using URLS

--it has explicit relationship with HTTP methods namely GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

--highly re useable across the platform

Answer (score 1):

A Rest WS is a service which you call, which returns data in a REST format.

A Servlet is a bit of UI that shows information to the user.

They are very different, although a Servlet could get the information that it displays from a Rest web service.